# Import Multiple Text Files into Seperate Excel Rows on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 50 text files and they all contain anything between 10-25 lines,

I am looking for a way to import all 50 text files into a single excel sheet with each text files content going into a single row.

So with 50 text files I'd expect 50 rows of text containing anything between 10-25 lines per row.

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution i assume, that you have a list of file pathes to the files you want to read.
To achive your desired result i propose to pass an input stream of each file to a String variable and store them in an Array, with length of number of input files. In the end you can write the Array to a Range. As a result one cell will contain the content of each input file split into lines within the cell.

```
Sub readTxtFiles(filePathList As Variant)
Dim strFileContent As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
'Array with length of number of input files
Dim contentArray As Variant
ReDim contentArray(UBound(filePathList))

i = 0
For Each filePath In filePathList
    'Open file and store content to strFileContent and close file
    Open filePath For Input As #iFile
    strFileContent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
    Close #iFile
    'Store content in output array 
    contentArray(i) = strFileContent
    'Clear content variable and increment i
    strFileContent = ""
    i = i + 1
Next filePath

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A"& Ubound(filePathList)) = contentArray
End Sub
```

EDIT:

Since you have the file locations also stored in a file, you can use the following code to pass it to an array found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883676/how-to-populate-an-array-from-text-file-in-visual-basic-for-powerpoint-2010/23883818)

```
Function readPathList(path as String) As Variant
    Dim sFile As String, sWhole As String
    Dim v As Variant
    sFile = "C:\mytxtfile.txt"
    Open sFile For Input As #1
    sWhole = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
    v = Split(sWhole, vbNewLine)
    readPathList= v
End Function
```

and then call

```
readTxtFiles(readPathList('Path to your list'))
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am unsure exactly where to input the filelist. I have generated the location for all 50 files as a text file also.