# Query runtime in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two very large files of which both field 1's have similar data. Now I want to use a query to compare these two files and output all rows of a particular column (Field3) in which file1.field1==file2.field1. This can of course be done with a simple query. I can not use join since there is too much text in the fields, so I use WHERE but this apparantly slows down the query by a lot.

Query:

```
SELECT Category_list.Field3
FROM Category_list, Uri_list
WHERE (Category_list.Field1=Uri_list.Field1);
```

Now this query is running, but I have no idea how long it will take. It could be a few hours but it wouldn't surprise me if it takes days. **Is it possible to see in access how far into the query it is, so that I can get at least an idea of what the runtime will be?**

Category_list has about 2.8 million rows and Uri_list has about 4 million rows. If needed I could lower the Uri_list to about 100.000 rows minimum, but that depends on the runtime..

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Im confused as to why you cant use a join? This is literally what theyre for? You could just use the files as files, and try and put contents into an array and process that way - wouldn't take too terribly long but requires some extra coding.

Comment: I just started using Access 2016 today so I'm still very much researching. But when I did it with a join I got this error: "access 2016 cannot join on memo ole or hyperlink object". I googled this and it said here (https://improvingsoftware.com/2011/03/15/how-to-join-on-memo-fields-in-microsoft-access/) that I should use WHERE because there are too many characters in my fields or something.

Comment: Ah yes. It has nothing to do with being able to join - its just that access treats fields with character size>255 as memo fields. SO the issue is actually a data type mismatch but access is throwing a different error. I wish theyd fix this but whatever. Youre going to have write some code yay! Do you per chance have sql server linked tables?

Comment: No it's two .txt files that I'm trying to compare

Comment: OK then this should be easy. Check the second unmarked answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883676/how-to-populate-an-array-from-text-file-in-visual-basic-for-powerpoint-2010  THEN check this on how to loop through multidimensional array. https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/loop-through-array-with-vba-ubound/ THEN figure out how to store the third column into anew array (or a table since youre in access). BOOM done

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

- **Import** both files into Access as local tables, using the text import assistant
- Create an index in both tables on Field1. If the values are unique, an unique index or even better a PrimaryKey; if not, a non-unique index.
- Create a simple query with JOIN

This should run fast enough.

> Is it possible to see in access how far into the query it is, so that I can get at least an idea of what the runtime will be?

Sometimes (especially for Update queries), Access shows a progress bar. But if not, no - there is no way to see the progress.

Comment: I just started learning Access today so this might be a way too basic question, but why does indexing it make it faster? And should I then also index that Field3? Also, I got this "access 2016 cannot join on memo ole or hyperlink object" error when using JOIN. I googled that error and it said that my fields contain too many characters so I had to use WHILE.

Comment: This is what [indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) do. :) -- Does your Field1 actually contain more than 255 chars in any row? If yes, then a JOIN indeed won't work. If no, change the data type to Text(255) / Short Text before creating the index. -- (Do you mean WHERE instead of WHILE?) -- No, Field3 doesn't need an index. @Knarf

Comment: Thanks for the link :) They're actually rarely longer than 255 chars per row, so I could throw out those lines I guess. If I change the data type to Text(255), while it automatically cut of the characters after the threshold? And where do I find this change data type button? I looked for it earlier today and I couldn't find it haha

Comment: Yes it will cut off the texts (and will warn you about that). -- Open the table in Design view, and just change the data type, there is no button.

Comment: Found it! I was incorrect though, seems like a lot more lines have above 255 chars than I expected. So I can't really use that. I see I can also put the data type on LongText, would that allow me to use your method? Both field1's were set as Hyperlink by the way.

Comment: Try it. :) I don't have much experience with Memo / Long Text data in Access, my data is usually in Sql Server. You should still be able to create the indexes, and they should also speed up your original query `WHERE (Category_list.Field1=Uri_list.Field1)`.  (Again: WHILE = WHERE?)

Comment: Oh yes WHILE = WHERE, was just a typo on stackoverflow though luckily :) I just checked and apparantly LongText is a form of Memo so I can't use that with JOIN either. I'm going to try my previous query with the indexing :)

Comment: How likely is it that two values of `Field1` will be identical for the first 255 characters and then be different? If it is likely split Field1 into two text fields and compare with both.

Comment: Hmm while it's running I'm also looking at my data and for some reason the ShortText cut-off seems to be wrong? For example: "<http://nl.dbpedia.org/resource/2014_World_Ports_Classic>" changes to "<http://nl.dbpedia.org/resource/2014_World_Ports_C" when I put that field as ShortText. That's 50 chars instead of 255 chars? Could this be some setting that ShortText is defined as 50 chars in my Access or something?

Comment: Hmm the "field size" in field properties was set as 50, so I changed that to 255 thinking it would fix it. But now the cut-off is at 58 chars somehow..

Comment: Nevermind, I did something wrong while importing. Works with join now! :) Thanks for the help!